# What is the difference between nominal, categorical, ordinal, interval and ratio measurements?

Tags: statistics

Given the following examples, which are examples of nominal, categorical, ordinal, interval or ratio measurements?

- bushels of wheat per county
- vegetation type
- average maximum daily temperature
- parcel street address
- parcel ID number
- pH measurements of a stream
- state rank for average wage
- number of voters in a district
- student grade in a class
- soil type

In particular, I am having trouble figuring out which one is a ratio measurement.

Comment: There are many different correct answers, because part of what goes into this classification of measurements is *how* they will be used in an analysis. For instance, pH measurements *when understood as hydrogen ion concentrations* are archetypal *ratio* measurements, merely re-expressed on a log scale. Likewise, a strong case could be made that a student grade is on a ratio scale--and an equally strong case can be made that it is only on an ordinal scale. If there is any merit in this exercise it lies in having you think through these issues, but there is little value in "the" right answer.

Comment: Maybe it belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [Level of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale):

> The ratio type takes its name from the fact that measurement is the estimation of the ratio between a magnitude of a continuous quantity and a unit magnitude of the same kind (Michell, 1997, 1999). A ratio scale possesses a meaningful (unique and non-arbitrary) zero value.

Here is a good article explaining the [differences between categorical, ordinal, and interval](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/nominal_ordinal_interval.htm).